# Логика работы Фрагментов в Фрагменте

Tags: java, android

Есть у меня фрагент, у него есть контроллер и адаптер.
Хочу сделать диалоговое окно тоже через фрашмент, у него не будет не контроллера,ни модели,так как кнопки обработчика обраюотаю в самом фрагменте,есть ли это правильным?

Comment: Ваш вопрос и Заголовок ну никак не соответствуют. Мб вы имели ввиду логика работы?

Comment: смотря какую логику вы собираетесь там обрабатывать .